# Javascript table td's index

Tags: javascript

I use this code to get the index of a td in a table:

```
  var tdIndex = this || (e || event).target;
  var index = tdIndex.cellIndex;
```

The problem is that each row's index starts again at 0;
For example, the index of the first cell of the first row is 0. Similarly, The index of the first cell in the second row is also 0, and so on. I don't want the index to be reset to 0 for each row in a table. I want the index number to continue where it left off in the last cell of the previous row.

Comment: Please share the complete code

Comment: Try to get the row count along with the index so you can easily identify the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your cell for it's parent row then get the [`rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex).

```
var rowIndex = e.target.parentElement.rowIndex;
```

The above code assumes that `e` is your event and `target` is your cell. Your `(e || event)` code isn't really necessary since you decide what your event object is named based on how your declare your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need take into account the `rowIndex` property to get unique number for the cell in each.

Ideally each cell is defined in JS as a unique pair of (`rowIndex,cellIndex`)

```
var tdIndex = this || (e || event).target;
var index = tdIndex.cellIndex + 1000 * tdIndex.rowIndex;
```

note that you can use any number instead of 1000. It should just be greater than the maximum number of columns in the table

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may do the trick and will work even if the number of cells is not the same on every row:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('#table__base');
const cellOne = document.querySelector('#cellOne');
const cellTwo = document.querySelector('#cellTwo');

function getIndex(table, cell) {
  let counter = 0;

  for (let i = 0, len = cell.parentNode.rowIndex; i <= len; i += 1) {
    let numberOfCellsInThisRow = (i === cell.parentNode.rowIndex) ? cell.cellIndex : table.rows[i].cells.length;
    counter += numberOfCellsInThisRow;
  }
  return counter;
}

console.log(getIndex(table, cellOne));
console.log(getIndex(table, cellTwo));
```

```html
<table id="table__base">
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td id="cellOne">9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td id="cellTwo">14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```